# Adding at UITapGestureRecognizer (double tap) to a UIButton slows down setting the button image as selected

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a double tap gesture on a UIButton. I have two different background images for unselected and selected states.

All of the functionality works, but when I touch the button, there is a delay in changing the background image for the selected state.

There is no delay if I get rid of the double tap gesture.

How can I get rid of this delay and still keep the double tap gesture?

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, it's waiting until it can be sure you're not double tapping before the single tap that the button wants is recognised. Likely there's some stuff built into `UIView` to help the gesture recognisers disambiguate and `UIButton` is using a recogniser to do its stuff.

With that in mind, have you considered synthesising a double tap based on the existing `UIControl` callout? So e.g. you'd have:

```
- (IBAction)buttonWasTapped:(id)sender // wired up to the button
{
    NSTimeInterval timeNow = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    NSTimeInterval difference = timeNow - timeThen;
    timeThen = timeNow; // an instance variable

    if(difference < kYourAllowedTimeBetweenTaps)
    {
        timeThen = 0.0; // to avoid capture of triple taps, etc
        [self buttonWasDoubleTapped:sender];
        return;
    }

    // do normal single tap processing here, if any
}
```